# Java, SWT, the image transparencity gets lost when resizing

Tags: java, swt

Im displaying .png image with transparencity which works well by default... until I resize the image:

```
public Image resize(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    Image scaled = new Image(Display.getDefault(), width, height);
    scaled.getImageData().transparentPixel = image.getImageData().transparentPixel;
    GC gc = new GC(scaled);
    gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
    gc.setInterpolation(SWT.HIGH);
    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0,image.getBounds().width, image.getBounds().height, 0, 0, width, height);
    gc.dispose();
    return scaled;
}
```

then the transparency is gone, I can see the "white" color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getImageData()` gives you a copy of the image data so setting the transparent pixel on that does not change the original image.

Instead you need to create another image from the scaled image data with the transparent pixel set. So something like:

```
Image scaled = new Image(Display.getDefault(), width, height);
GC gc = new GC(scaled);
gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
gc.setInterpolation(SWT.HIGH);
gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0,image.getBounds().width, image.getBounds().height, 0, 0, width, height);
gc.dispose();

// Image data from scaled image and transparent pixel from original

ImageData imageData = scaled.getImageData();

imageData.transparentPixel = image.getImageData().transparentPixel;

// Final scaled transparent image

Image finalImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(), imageData);

scaled.dispose();
```

Note that this only works when the original image data has the same format as the scaled image data (particularly the palette data)

If the data is in a different format use:

```
ImageData origData = image.getImageData();

imageData.transparentPixel = imageData.palette.getPixel(origData.palette.getRGB(origData.transparentPixel));
```

Comment: sorry its not working, transparency is still gone (and gc.dispose() should go to the last line, since gs is still used)

Comment: Possibly the image data formats are different, in which case working out the value for the transparent pixel is harder. Try something like `imageData.transparentPixel = imageData.getPixel(0, 0);` which uses the top left pixel as the transparent color.

Comment: Added some code which I think should work if the image formats are different